# CSS Media Query not over riding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I've always done `max-width` media queries, but I know bootstrap does `min-width` style media queries, and I'm trying to follow that style on my current project.

I have the following class declaration (no media query here)

```
.Mobilemenutrigger {
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 12px;
    background: #6bb854;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Then following bootstrap's media query conventions, I have the following

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .Mobilemenutrigger {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

However when I view this in my browser, the original declaration is being applied, and the media query is not over riding the original as I thought it should.

I know I can throw an `!important` onto the media query, but I was under the impression I don't need to when doing `min-width` style media queries. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Make sure you put media query rule **after** normal one.

Comment: hmm... they are in separate files, I wonder if I move the media queries file include after my main css include if that would make a difference

Comment: Yes this this the issue. Move media queries file after your main css file.

Comment: That was it... I moved my media queries css file to be included after my main css. All is working as intended. If you put that into an answer I will happily accept it

Comment: I think it would be fair to accept the answer of IAteYourKitten, as it's technically correct, although downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the load order for your files?  If the main.css is being loaded after the media.css it won't function properly.  Try appending the media.css last and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the browser is reading your media queries AFTER it has read the initial class properties.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed the last paragraph of your post about !important attributes.

Comment: Entirely unnecessary for this example if you use media queries correctly

Comment: The fix is in my answer tho.  I made a mistake and will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Due to same [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), you must add mediaquery AFTER initial declaration.

If you invert order, it will result in an ovverride of general rule over the mediaquery's one.

Written in this exact order, it will run correctly as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c1txa9fs/):

```
.Mobilemenutrigger {
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 12px;
    background: #6bb854;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .Mobilemenutrigger {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Instead, if you invert order, and you have screen wider than 768px, first, mediaquery would set `display: none;`, and then more general rule would override it with `display: inline-block;`